# What will be the probability of p(X>x+y|X>x)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

How to calculate the conditional probability of a random variable which is greater than some value.

Comment: what is the distribution of your variable?

Comment: The distribution is not given

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of conditional probability:

$$ \Pr(X>x+y \vert X>x) = \frac{\Pr(X>x+y, \, X>x)}{\Pr(X>x)} $$

Where we can say 
$$ \Pr(X>x+y, \, X>x) = \Pr(X>x+y) $$
for some $y\geq 0$. Otherwise
$$ \Pr(X>x+y, \, X>x) = \Pr(X>x) $$
for $y<0$.

Therefore

- for $y<0$:
  $$ \Pr(X>x+y \vert X>x) = 1$$
- for $y\geq0$:
  $$ \Pr(X>x+y \vert X>x) =\frac{\Pr(X>x+y)}{\Pr(X>x)} $$

Comment: But definition of *memory less* is  [from here](http://www.statisticshowto.com/memoryless-property/)
$$\Pr(X>x+y \vert X>x)=\Pr(X>y)$$

Comment: Thankyou everyone. I got it.

Comment: What about when $P(X>x)=0$. Conditional probability is defined. But your answer doesn't cover that

Comment: That is a good point, isn't it trivial that it should be non-zero?

Comment: @pointguard0 Your comment is quite wrong.